# Should I download all the SDK's between min and maxSdkVersion

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an android app and it should work between SDK versions 15-20. Should I download all of these SDK's or the latest one is enough?

Comment: its not necessory to download all SDK... you just have to download maximum level SDK for running your app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No just just download the version 20 and compile your project against it. just mention the minimum and maximum sdk in the manifest file-

```
android:minSdkVersion="15"
android:targetSdkVersion="20"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to have the lastest version of the SDK. While creating a new project you will be setting the min & max target versions of Android that this app will be compatible with.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Answer (score 0):

Just download the SDK for Version 20.

While creating/importing your project make sure that you compile it with version 20 else it'll give errors.

Also make sure that you make an entry in your manifest file stating your min and max version supported.

```
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="15"
     android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it enough just download minimum version and maximum versions sdk versions.